# SoundCloud Cross-Origin Request Blocked at https://l9bjkkhaycw6f8f4.soundcloud.com/v1/events

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am trying to use the Soundcloud widget API found [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget).

I have my Iframe

```
<iframe id="SCIframe"></iframe
```

I included the script

```
<script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, I execute this script in a function.

```
var scPlayer;
var iframeSoundcloud = document.getElementById("SCIframe");
iframeSoundcloud.src = "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url="+encodeURIComponent(lien);
        scPlayer = SC.Widget("SCIframe");

scPlayer.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function(){
            scPlayer.play();
        });
```

When the page first loaded, the soundcloud song plays well. But when I call it another time without refreshing the page, I get ***Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://l9bjkkhaycw6f8f4.soundcloud.com/v1/events. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*').*** message, and the song cannot play.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from the Iframe. I generate a new Iframe every-time I want to play a new song.

```
var frameSCID = "scIframe"+new Date().getMilliseconds();
        var iframeSC = $('<iframe></iframe>');
        iframeSC.attr({"id":frameSCID, "src":"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url="+encodeURIComponent(lien)});

        $("#scIframeContainer").html(iframeSC);
        scPlayer = SC.Widget(frameSCID);

...
```

If someone has a better way to fix it. I'm waiting

Comment: SO isn't an advice forum. You've answered your question to please mark it correct.

Comment: No it is not. I just fixed my problem. But, generate an iframe every-time a new song gonna play looks costly to me. I hope, I get a better answer. And I can't mark my answer until 2 days from now.